# google-maps kml, how to label a line string?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a website that displays kml Line Strings as bike routes on google-maps.

I would like to label the routes but have not been able to do so.
I have not been able to add a bubble to the Line String.  I put a Placemark along the route, and it shows up as an icon but i could not find a way to put a label on them.  I could not change the icon to a png icon with the text I need.

I have been trying different things, generally looking at these documents but just trying a lot of different things.

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps

I don't know for sure if it is just not possible or if I am doing something wrong.

The only thing I can think of is to draw a Line String in Google Earth in the shape of the characters I need for my label, in the location I want to display it, but that seems silly, it should be easier than that.

Has anyone been able to add labels in a kml file for display in google-map API 3?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, I believe it has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6733780/1314132). Also, in your question you talk about changing a Placemark icon and there is a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905453/1314132) that I believe addresses that part of your question. Hope this helps -

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either of the links in the most popular answer gets to the heart of this question. For anyone looking to do something like the following:

[image]

Here you go. Just make sure your line string is longer than the length of the name, otherwise, it will be hidden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KmlFile</name>
    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>5</width>
            <gx:physicalWidth>5</gx:physicalWidth>
            <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin">
        <BalloonStyle>
        </BalloonStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>5</width>
            <gx:physicalWidth>5</gx:physicalWidth>
            <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>My Path Name</name>
        <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                -120.4845966202045,34.72793226888417,0 -120.4872080139926,34.71875037771856,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```